# Passing nullable value to a method

Tags: c#, silverlight, mef

How i can pass nullable value to a method

```
[Import("Default", typeof(ISomeInterface), AllowRecomposition = true, AllowDefault = true)]
public ISomeInterface x { get; set; }
// x is null till now 
void DoWork(ISomeInterface obj) //Not working
{
        if (obj == null)
        {
            //Download and Satisfy
            DeploymentCatalog DC = new DeploymentCatalog("TheXAPfile.xap");
            DC.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(f); //catalog is AggregateCatalog
                obj.Show();
            };
            DC.DownloadAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            obj.Show();
        }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's not working? Do you have a value type that implements `ISomeInterface`?

Comment: Show the code part where actual error happens and a message it gives (if any), or, on compiler error, post the compiler message.

Comment: System.NullReferenceExcption: [Arg_NullRefrenceException]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are assuming that obj is null when you start the async download, and that someway it's no more null when DownloadCompleted is triggered. Is there something that you didn't show that guarantee you this condition is satisfied? What are you doing after DownloadAsync, and how can you be sure that this will be evaluated before the completion of the download?

```
    if (obj == null) 
    {
        //// you enter here only if obj is null
        //Download and Satisfy
        DeploymentCatalog DC = new DeploymentCatalog("TheXAPfile.xap");
        DC.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(f); //catalog is AggregateCatalog
            //// here you are assuming that obj is not null anymore. Why???
            obj.Show();
        };
        DC.DownloadAsync();
    }
```

Comment: +1: Yep, it is simply the use of `obj.Show();` when obj is obviously still null that is causing the problem. EBKAC!

Comment: that was the problem 
I have added the line
    if(ISomeInterface != null) ISomeInterface.Show();
and worked fine 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Exception is result of using some method or property of the `obj` when its null. You have to check if its null on your own

```
void DoWork(ISomeInterface obj) //Not working
{
    if(obj == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    /* do something ... */}
}
```

Comment: This is correct. This has nothing to do with nullable types, but to check if an object is null or not on your own.

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved by placing a ? after the object type in your function header.

```
void DoWork(ISomeInterface? obj)
```

Comment: Unless `ISomeInterface` is a horribly named value type, that's not legal, and superfluous to boot (since interface variables can be `null` already.)

Comment: Actually interfaces are reference type and it's no necessary to add `?` at the end to pass `null`..